# HTTP request not getting data in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

When I use I paste this link in a browser or even an IDE in my local environment (Webstorm) I get JSON data but when I try to use this function in Lambda it returns an empty string (so the variable *datastring* is empty)

```js
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = function(event,context,callback){

    let dataString = '';
    
    const req = https.get("https://www.instagram.com/dev1398/?__a=1", function(res) {
      res.on('data', chunk => {
        dataString += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        // console.log(JSON.parse(dataString));
        console.log(dataString)
      });
    });
    
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error log for the above lambda function?

Comment: `https.put`? for get?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
const req = https.get("https://www.instagram.com/dev1398/?__a=1", function(res) {
       res.on('data', chunk => {
       dataString += chunk;
    });
```

in place of

```
const req = https.put("https://www.instagram.com/dev1398/?__a=1", function(res) {
    res.on('data', chunk => {
       dataString += chunk;
});
```

You need to use `GET` method instead of `PUT`

Comment: I did use GET instead of put but that resulted in an empty console log